# Magento Widget does not show up on CMS pages and product pages, but on the home page and category pages it is visible

Tags: templates, magento, static, widget, block

I have a custom Magento widget showing a list of categories on the bottom. This widget is placed within a static block, and the static block is added to the template.

This is the content of the static block:

```
test output
{{widget type="mylinks/view" template="mywidgets/mylinks.phtml" parent_category="1"}}
```

The strange thing is that the widget does show up on the home page and in all category pages. But it is not shown on product detail pages and on CMS pages. The only thing I see there is "test output" (which proves that the static block is there).

I added a "test widget output" in the widget template "mywidgets/mylinks.phtml". But it is also not displayed. It seems like the template is not parsed at all, because an php-exit-command there will be ignored also!

It is hard to debug when not having an output...

Comment: Have you turned on template path hints in magento debug? A lot of times this can be useful in pointing out potential issues with the templating system ...

Comment: have you changed your design theme from cms pages?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself: the widget code I have used to build my own has overwritten the output method with its own having an if-condition which was false after my adjustments.

Thanks anyway for ideas!

Comment: Great you found an answer and thanks for sharing. Please accept it by checking the checkmark outline next to your answer, that lets evverybody know your problem is solved.